# disable firebug on site when loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

Is it possible to disable firebug when a page is loaded?

I tried:

```
console.disabled;
```

...but didn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know think you can disable firebug completely from your own javascript. If you could, then ght GMail team would have included that in their code [;)]. Instead they proffer a warning that says "firebug makes me slow".

But, perhaps [this](http://davidwalsh.name/how-to-sniff-firebug-disable) will help?